# AppCompact cause ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: android

AppCompact cause ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception, during method setContentView, i tried various solutions i could search here but its not helping. its including inherit from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Also when i extends my activity from FragmentActivity, it works normally

the stack trace is:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1926; index=-91619004
at android.content.res.TypedArray.hasValue(TypedArray.java) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:341) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.itp.android.retailer.epayment.splashscreen.ActivitySplashScreen.onCreate(ActivitySplashScreen.java:31)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
```

Activity on create:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    ...
}
```

values/style.xml

```
<!-- for when ExtendedActivity extends from v7 ApPCompactActivity -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

gradle, just in case

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
}
}
```

Comment: What is ActivitySplashScreen.java:31 ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: show `style.xml` also

Comment: ActivitySplashScreen is the Launcher Activity, no special thing there, will edit my question